# Can I use nested generics (aka higher kinded types) in Java?

Tags: java, generics, higher-kinded-types

I was trying to do something like:

```
public class MyClass <A, B, C <A, B> > {
  ...
}
```

But Eclipse highlights "B," and says "unexpected , expected extends".  What gives?  Are nested generics not allowed?

Comment: It's allowed.
Show your actual classes if you want...

Comment: @Doug: Given your responses to the answers below, I suspect some deeper confusion is at work here.  Perhaps you could post some more sample code, showing how you expect clients of `MyClass` should be able to use it, and that might make your question clearer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you haven't defined `C` as a type that is itself typed with 2 type parameters.
Try something like this:

```
public class MyClass <A, B, C extends Map<A, B>> {
    // This compiles
}
```

Comment: But what if C can be one of several classes that do not have a common parent class?

Comment: @Doug: If there is no common supertype to C, then how do you know it needs to be parameterized?  If you just mean literally having the same parent class, then that's not actually necessary if the `extends` constraint is on an interface, since Java supports multiple interface inheritance.

Comment: @Daniel, right, I think that's the answer here is I should be using an interface in that third template slot. And if I'm trying to use built in Java classes with it, then I need to use an interface that they implement and that my classes also implement. If that's not good enough, doesn't cover all the functionality I need, then the built in classes can't provide it either, so it is inappropriate to use both. I think that's the answer to the situation.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer, but really it's because of the combination of this answer and Daniel's comments.

Answer (score 3):

If your template parameters don't share share a class hierarchy, you can use an interface.

For example:

```
interface IConverter<TFrom, TTo>
{
    TTo convert(TFrom from);
}

class IntToStringConverter implements IConverter<Integer, String>
{
    public String convert(Integer from)
    {
        return "This is a string: " + from.toString();
    }
}

class ConverterUser<TConverter extends IConverter<TFrom, TTo>, TFrom, TTo>
{
    public ConverterUser()
    {
    }

    private List<TConverter> _converter2;

    private TConverter _converter;

    public void replaceConverter(TConverter converter)
    {
        _converter = converter;
    }

    public TTo convert(TFrom from)
    {
        return _converter.convert(from);
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ConverterUser<IntToStringConverter, Integer, String> converterUser =
            new ConverterUser<IntToStringConverter, Integer, String>();

        converterUser.replaceConverter(new IntToStringConverter());

        System.out.println(converterUser.convert(328));
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot about the "extends" capability in templates, so maybe this type of thing could also work.

Comment: Dan, I liked this answer, but I think the best answer would be a combination of this one and the currently accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in Java.  See the [Type Variables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#108850) section of the language definition along with [Generic Classes and Type Parameters](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#299360).  I recently saw (somewhere) a mention that Java is incapable of this but Scala can do it.  This is confirmed by S4.4 of the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

This is also somewhat confirmed by the following code compiling successfully.

```
class MyClass [A, B, C [A, B]] {
}
```

Compiling in java yielded the follwing answers.

```
MyClass.java:1: > expected
class MyClass <A, B, C<A, B>> {
                      ^
MyClass.java:1: <identifier> expected
class MyClass <A, B, C<A, B>> {
                        ^
MyClass.java:1: ';' expected
class MyClass <A, B, C<A, B>> {
                           ^
MyClass.java:2: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
4 errors
```

I would guess that there is an easier solution to your problem however, as this is somewhat unusual.

Comment: There was a solution, but I was still interested in knowing whether it was possible at all for the sake of curiosity or future designs where it might have been a FAR better solution.  In this case it wasn't a really big deal, although it still would have made things smoother.

Comment: Until I saw this answer, I was puzzling over why such syntax would not be allowed. Thanks for bringing up Scala.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to declare nested types like that. Simply

```
class MyClass<A, B, C> {}
```

And when you create a MyClass, you could do something like

```
MyClass<List<String>, Set<Date>, Map<Integer, Long>> instance;
```

Comment: I tried this, but then the compiler complained when I tried to instantiate C's with something like C<A, B> = new C<A, B>();

Comment: @Doug: C is a type parameter. It's not instantiable. Maybe if you take a step back and explain more broadly what problem you're trying to solve, someone can point out a better path to a solution.

Comment: So my real problem is that in general type parameters are not instantiable.  What about a child class that uses C as a template parameter?  Is that permitted?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want MyClass to be a generic class with type parameters A, B, and C.  Furthermore you want C to be a generic class with type parameters A and B.

So that I could write

1. `MyClass < String , Date , Map < String , Date > >`
2. `MyClass < String , Date , Hashtable < String , Date > >`
   but not
3. `MyClass < String , Date , ElementVsitor < Date , String > >`

Then I don't think you can do that.

Comment: That's exactly what I want.  Hmm, I suspected that might be the case, and it's unfortunate because it will lead to a lot of code duplication.

Comment: Actually I am  struggling to think of a use case.  So what code would be duplicated?

Comment: Well, I'm working on something that has the same interface as map, and is sometimes used with map as a child class, but can also be used with a user defined class as a child class in which case functionality is extended by giving new meaning to get, put, etc.

Comment: @Doug: `Map` is not a class, it's an interface.  (At least not if you mean `java.util.Map`.)  The whole point of using interfaces is that they define the set of valid operations on a type.  If your generic types don't share a common interface, then how is your code supposed to manipulate them?

Comment: @Daniel, right, I think that's the answer here is I should be using an interface in that third template slot.  And if I'm trying to use built in Java classes with it, then I need to use an interface that they implement and that my classes also implement.  If that's not good enough, doesn't cover all the functionality I need, then the built in classes can't provide it either, so it is inappropriate to use both.  I think that's the answer to the situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is effectively asking for higher order types in Java. Java does not support this directly, but it [can be simulated](https://github.com/highj/highj) in a somewhat roundabout way like so

```
interface H<K, T> { }
```

Here `H` encodes a higher order type that takes a type parameter `K` which itself takes parameter `T`.

You can use this to e.g. implement a generic functor. Note how `fmap` is effectively a function from `H<K<T>>` to `H<K<R>>` although we cannot directly declare it that way.

```
public interface Functor<K> {
    <T, R> Function<H<K, T>, H<K, R>> lift(Function<T, R> f);

    default <T, R> H<K, R> fmap(Function<T, R> f, H<K, T> h) {
        return lift(f).apply(h);
    }
}
```

See also my [Github repository](https://github.com/mduerig/java-functional/blob/master/src/michid/fun/TypeClass.java) for full working examples.
Further more have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70681453/how-to-implement-fixed-points-of-functors-in-java), which takes the concept much further still.