# Java F-Bound types with generics

Tags: java, generics, functor, bounded-wildcard

Is there any way to express f-bound types in java where at the call site, a generic response is returned?

```
interface Functor<T extends Functor<T>>
  public <B> T<B> map(Function<A, B> fn); // won't compile because types don't match
```

I can use f-bound types if the type never changes, but in the case of map, I need a new type.  Is there a way to express this in java?

What I am really looking for is any way that I can get something like higher kinds even though I know javac doesn't support higher kinded types.

Lets say we have a `List<A>` and want this interface to return a `List<B>`.  But don't want this interface to know anything about `List`.

Comment: `interface Functor<T extends Functor<T>, A, B>` ?

Comment: That wont let me return a `T<B>` in the map.  My current type would be a T<A>, and I need to return a T<B>.

Comment: So where did `A` come from?  It's not formally defined anywhere.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to figure out.  Maybe I am looking at this in terms of higher order types,  Updated my comment to reflect this better.

Comment: Can you add an example of the usage you're thinking of? With what would you call Functor.map, what would you expect returned?

Comment: See this answer on how to encode higher order types in Java: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451658/can-i-use-nested-generics-aka-higher-kinded-types-in-java/70721895#answer-70721895

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the Wikipedia definition of functor, it sounds like you want to define a generic type which is able to map from one category (Java type) to another. In your example above, to map from a `List<A>` to `List<B>` where the types `A` and `B` are generic.

If this is your aim, then consider the following interface for the definition of a `Functor` type:

```
public interface Functor<CategoryA, CategoryB> {
    public CategoryB map(CategoryA instance);
}
```

This declares that the `Functor` type deals in two generic parameter types, `CategoryA` and `CategoryB` and no constraints are put on these parameter types. It also declares that a method `map` must be implemented which maps from an object of type `CategoryA` to an object of type `CategoryB`.

Suppose, based on your example, you now want to create a concrete instance of a `Functor` which maps from `List<Integer>` to `List<String>`. You might create the following class:

```
public class IntegerListToStringList implements Functor<List<Integer>, List<String>> {
    @Override
    public List<String> map(List<Integer> integerList) {
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(integerList.size());
        for(Integer intValue : integerList) {
            stringList.add(Integer.toString(intValue));
        }
        return stringList;
    }
}
```

You could then invoke this concrete `Functor` implementation like so:

```
Functor<List<Integer>, List<String>> functor = new IntegerListToStringList();
Integer[] intArray = new Integer[] {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13};
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(intArray);
List<String> stringList = functor.map(intList);
System.out.println("String list: " + stringList);
```

Now any method which is expecting a parameter of type `Functor<List<Integer>, List<String>>` can accept an instance of type `IntegerListToStringList`.

Comment: That should work find if I make the `ListFunctor<A, B>` class paramitorized.  The higher kinded part is to scope it down so the input and the output have the same outer type (list in this example), but could lower this requirement by making all basic impls provide it...