# Can java infer the generic type from a class defined on top of generics?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, nested-generics

I've borrowed the code from this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7451812/1824105)

```
interface IConverter<TFrom, TTo>
{
    TTo convert(TFrom from);
}

class IntToStringConverter implements IConverter<Integer, String>
{
    public String convert(Integer from)
    {
        return "This is a string: " + from.toString();
    }
}

class ConverterUser<TConverter extends IConverter<TFrom, TTo>, TFrom, TTo>
{
    public ConverterUser()
    {
    }

    private List<TConverter> _converter2;

    private TConverter _converter;

    public void replaceConverter(TConverter converter)
    {
        _converter = converter;
    }

    public TTo convert(TFrom from)
    {
        return _converter.convert(from);
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ConverterUser<IntToStringConverter, Integer, String> converterUser =
            new ConverterUser<IntToStringConverter, Integer, String>();

        converterUser.replaceConverter(new IntToStringConverter());

        System.out.println(converterUser.convert(328));
    }
}
```

My question has to do with this piece of code

```
    ConverterUser<IntToStringConverter, Integer, String> converterUser =
        new ConverterUser<IntToStringConverter, Integer, String>();
```

As `IntToStringConverter` is implementing `IConverter<Integer, String>` , `Integer` and `String` type are known, doesn't java have an inference system to avoid typing `new ConverterUser<IntToStringConverter, Integer, String>()` and type just `new ConverterUser<IntToStringConverter>()` ?

Comment: Note that you can write it as  `ConverterUser<IntToStringConverter, Integer, String> converterUser =
        new ConverterUser<>();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

In the `ConverterUser` class definition, the `TFrom` and `TTo` type parameters have be to introduced **somewhere**, so that they are used in the `TConverter extends IConverter<TFrom, TTo>` type definition.

This is why the `ConverterUser` results with three type parameters.

Note that you can still get rid of the second and the third type parameters, but only if you define the first one to be **exactly** a sub-type of `IntToStringConverter`. However, I wouldn't advice you to do so, because this way the `ConverterUser` class will be *doomed* to convert only from `Integer` to `String`:

```
class ConverterUser<TConverter extends IntToStringConverter> {
    public ConverterUser() { ... }

    private TConverter _converter;

    public String convert(Integer from)
    {
        return _converter.convert(from);
    }
}
```