# How to implement fixed points of functors in Java

Tags: java, functor, higher-kinded-types, catamorphism, fixed-point-iteration

I recently discovered how to [simulate higher order types in Java](https://github.com/highj/highj)  in a somewhat roundabout way like so

```
interface H<F, T> { }
```

Here `H` encodes a higher order type that takes a type parameter `F` which itself takes parameter `T`.

Now this leaves me to wonder, can we use this to implement some more advanced constructs? E.g. fixed point of functors
like [Fix in Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-fix-0.3.0/docs/Data-Fix.html) and its corresponding [catamorphisms](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-fix-0.3.0/docs/Data-Fix.html#g:6)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed this can be done by carefully translating the corresponding Haskell counterparts. Although this introduces a lot of line noise,
the implementation is quite close to the original:

```java
// Encoding of higher kinded type F of T
public interface H<F, T> { }

public interface Functor<F, T> {
    <R> H<F, R> map(Function<T, R> f);
}

// newtype Fix f = Fix {unfix::f (Fix f)}
public static record Fix<F extends H<F, T> & Functor<F, T>, T>(F f) {
    public Functor<F, Fix<F, T>> unfix() {
        return (Functor<F, Fix<F, T>>) f;
    }
}

// type Algebra f a = f a -> a
public interface Algebra<F, T> extends Function<H<F, T>, T> {}

 // cata :: Functor f => Algebra f a -> Fix f -> a
 // cata alg = alg . fmap (cata alg) . unfix
public static <F extends H<F, T> & Functor<F, T>, T> Function<Fix<F, T>, T> cata(Algebra<F, T> alg) {
    return fix -> alg.apply(fix.unfix().map(cata(alg)));
}
```

Amazingly this works and can be used to implement e.g. [interpreters for expression algebras](https://github.com/mduerig/java-functional/blob/master/src/michid/fun/fix/Expression.java#L25)

```java
// evalExprF :: Algebra ExprF Int
// evalExprF (Const n) = n
// evalExprF (Add m n) = m + n
// evalExprF (Mul m n) = m * n
public static class ExprAlg implements Algebra<Expr, Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(H<Expr, Integer> hExpr) {
        return Expr.expr(hExpr).match(
            conzt -> conzt.n,
            add   -> add.t1 + add.t2,
            mul   -> mul.t1 * mul.t2);
    }
}
```

Full working example in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/mduerig/java-functional).