# Writing a parametrized method where parameter has to be parametrized again

Tags: generics, java-17, higher-kinded-types

I am working with Websockets in java. I have to implement a method that takes in a generic message handler. So I wrote like this and it compiles.

```
public <T, M extends MessageHandler> boolean addMessageHandler(Class<T> clazz, M messageHandler) {
}
```

But when I try to be more specific, it throws compile time errors.

```
public <T, M<T> extends MessageHandler> boolean addMessageHandler(Class<T> clazz, M<T> messageHandler) {
}
```

Errors I get:

1. **Cannot resolve symbol 'T'**
2. **'>' expected.**

How can I solve this issue?

The MessageHandler interface looks like this and this is a library method so I can't alter:

```
public interface MessageHandler {

    interface Partial<T> extends javax.websocket.MessageHandler {
        void onMessage(T messagePart, boolean last);
    }

    interface Whole<T> extends javax.websocket.MessageHandler {
        void onMessage(T message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this directly since Java does not have higher kinded types (i.e. `T<X>`).

You could try simulating higher kinded types via this trick I'm using here though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70681453/how-to-implement-fixed-points-of-functors-in-java

Comment: The fault lies with `MessageHandler`; it needs a type parameter that ties together the two kinds of handlers.  If it were generic in T and `Partial<T> extends MessageHandler<T>` (and same for Whole), you'd be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support this kind of composite generics. There is a workaround though:

1. Define a marker interface with the generic type `T`:

   ```
   interface Handler<T> {}
   ```
2. Define interfaces extending the provided interfaces that cannot be changed *and* the marker interface:

   ```
   interface PartialMessageHandler<T> extends MessageHandler.Partial<T>, 
                                              Handler<T> {}
   ```

   ```
   interface WholeMessageHandler<T> extends MessageHandler.Whole<T>, 
                                            Handler<T> {}
   ```
3. Redefine your method like this:

   ```
   public <T, M extends Handler<T>> boolean addMessageHandler(Class<T> clazz, M messageHandler) {
       return true;
   }
   ```