# Passing arguments to generic parameter in class in Java

Tags: java, scala, generics, types

I'm trying to figure out a mechanism to implement something like the following in Java. Essentially, I'd like to use the argument to a generic class as a generic class:

```java
class A<T> {
  T<String> aString;
}
```

Is this, or something equivalent, where I can pass arguments to the type constructor received as arguments, possible at all in Java? Is it possible to indicate that `T` has type `* -> *` or that it is some sort of type constructor? If not, how about a different language?

Comment: Don't know about scala, but Java does not have this. Perhaps this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: I'm literally just trying to build what I have there. I want to be able to "wrap" all members of a class in an argument generic (or type constructor) so that I can decide the behavior when I instantiate it. For example, an `A<Vector>` would contain a vector of strings, an `A<HashMap>` would contain a hash map of strings, and so on.

If I have two private members (e.g., a `String` and an `Integer`), and I wrap both with `T<>`, then `A<HashMap>` would have both a `HashMap<String>` and a `HashMap<Integer>`, and so on.

Comment: Have a look at this for Scala https://www.baeldung.com/scala/higher-kinded-types

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Java (but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451658/can-i-use-nested-generics-aka-higher-kinded-types-in-java) is probably relevant for you), but you can do this in Scala

```
final case class A[T[_], B](a: T[B])
```

And then you can instantiate classes like so, relying on type inference:

```
val a1 = A(List("hello", "world"))
val a2 = A(Some(42))
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/756EE9fNTnKIw67qxQmRYw).

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [higher-kinded type](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/higher-kinded-types). Here's an example in Scala of exactly what you want ([Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/TimMoore/YdiBBTCMQo2tS6Ii5ovOcQ/6)):

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
trait A[T[_]] {
  def aString: T[String]
}

class AVector extends A[Vector] {
  def aString: Vector[String] = Vector("Hello, world!")
}

type StringKeyedHashMap[T] = HashMap[String, T]
class AHashMap[T] extends A[StringKeyedHashMap] {
  def aString: HashMap[String, String] = HashMap(
    "Hello, world!" -> "Goodbye, world!"
  )
}


println((new AVector).aString)  // Vector(Hello, world!)
println((new AHashMap).aString) // HashMap(Hello, world! -> Goodbye, world!)
```

Note that in the `HashMap` example, it isn't possible to use `extends A[HashMap]`, because `HashMap` requires two type parameters, and `A[T[_]]` only accepts types that take a single parameter. To work around this, a [type alias](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/type-declaration) is declared that takes one type parameter for the map values, and hardcodes the key type as `String`.